# Why is the line number column missing in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I've been using Atom for a number of weeks, and recently the line number column is missing. The only associated change I can recall is having disabled the core wrap-guide package. I've tried enabling it and restarting. I have no custom CSS implemented.

Where in the settings or config is the line number toggle? What might've hidden it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Show Line Numbers" setting is under the "Editor Settings" heading in the main Settings window (ctrl+,).

Comment: Thank you. It's under the Invisibles section. I must have scrolled past that a dozen times.